# What are all the font faces that I can use?

Tags: html, fonts, font-face

I am new to designing pages, and am starting off with basic HTML.

```
<font face="arial">Text</font>
```

I understand that the above displays `Text` in arial font face.

What are all the options that I have to put in place of `arial`? Is there a list or something for this?

Comment: Oh. Don't lose your face, learn CSS today!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***What are all the font faces that I can use?***

You can choose what ever font face you like, but keep in mind that the browser will fall back on some other font if it does not have the particular font you're requesting to use.

The best thing you can do is to stick to some commonly available font faces. Here are a few good lists of such fonts:

- [list of safe fonts for use on a html webpage](http://web.archive.org/web/20110511043945/http://www.angelfire.com/fl5/html-tutorial/fontlist.htm)
- [HTML Font Face: Here is most common fonts](http://web.archive.org/web/20101213023008/http://bigoo.ws/help/help_font.aspx)
- [HTML Goodies Font List](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479591/So-You-Want-To-Change-Your-Font-Huh.htm)

Comment: Some of the above links don't seem to work.  This page tells you all you need to know: http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

Answer (score 5):

First, start using instead of using `<font>` tag, use CSS (ie. `font-family` - Reference: **[CSS font-family Property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_font_font-family.asp)**)

Then you can look over **[Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/)** to see all sort of fonts that you can use and are easy to adapt with your site.

For full tutorial on CSS start doing this entire series of tutorials with CSS : **[CSS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/default.asp)**

Also here is a list of safe web fonts: **[List of Web Safe Fonts](http://www.fonttester.com/help/list_of_web_safe_fonts.html)**

Answer (score 3):

Well now with google code you can do much more. Reade here: http://www.google.com/webfonts

below are the list of html "safe" font faces:

> arial, arial black, comic sans ms,
>   courier, courier new, georgia,
>   helvetica, impact, palatino, times new
>   roman, trebuchet ms, verdana

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You should never use a  element anymore, use CSS instead. Here's a list of the available font-families: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you use sans-serif instead of Arial.

Its a best of both worlds for mac (causes Helvetica to be displayed) and windows (causes Arial).

Furthermore check out http://www.google.com/webfonts if you want to embed some open-source sexy fonts

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out, you'd be best reconsidering use of the `font` tag and looking into using CSS (specifically the `font-family` and related rules, especially font stacking).

As far as what is commonly cited as "web safe" goes, it all depends what fonts are available on your users' computers, as these are the fonts that their browser will work with.

Also look into the CSS `@font-face` directive, and its usefulness with services like Google webfonts, Typekit, Font Deck and similar. It opens a whole other set of possibilities.

EDIT to remove broken link.

Comment: That resource is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeKormendy. Have edited to remove the reference.